# How to change color of a specific visual studio symbol in .JSON settings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, colors, themes, settings

So I created a nice green Theme for my visual Studio but there is one specific symbol which remained yellow from the previous theme [Here is a Screenshot of the strange yellow counter I want to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPZ4w.jpg) and I just can't find the json code to change its color because I don't know the name of the symbol. the symbol is the counter next to "Problems" please see the attached screenshot. So If anyone knows the name of the symbol or a website with more information it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these color theme references (here in a `settings.json`):

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "badge.background": "#a1a0a0",  // the badge colors for the problems
    "badge.foreground": "#fff",

    "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#fff",  // badge colors on the activity bar
    "activityBarBadge.background": "#a0a1a1"
  }
}
```

Since I knew those were "badges" of some sort, I used intellisense in the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object by typing "badge" and looking at the possibilities in the intellisense pop-up.

The full list is [theme color reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color).

Comment: omg thank you I was trying out so many of these settings but didn't think about badges ^^ yea it totally worked my theme is complete thank you very much <3